# Checking if a date string is in UTC format

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have a date string like "2011-11-06 14:00:00+00:00". Is there a way to check if this is in UTC format or not ?. I tried to convert the above string to a datetime object using `utc = datetime.strptime('2011-11-06 14:00:00+00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S+%z)` so that i can compare it with pytz.utc, but i get 'ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S+%z'

How to check if the date string is in UTC ?. Some example would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: @S.Lott, I don't think a lower-case `%z` is valid even in Python 3. If it is, then the [docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/time.html#time.strftime) are wrong.

Comment: @senderle: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.  You're saying the '%z' is only for strftime?  If so, then I think you should post that as the answer.

Comment: aside: the given string is actually *not* a valid iso-8601 datetime, but rather *two* valid values (one a date, the other a time).  The standard draws a rather bright line between date/time values joined with `T` and values that are otherwise merely adjacent.

Answer (score 5):

A simple regular expression will do:

```
>>> import re
>>> RE = re.compile(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}$')
>>> bool(RE.search('2011-11-06 14:00:00+00:00'))
True
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your format string is that `strptime` just passes the job of parsing time strings on to c's `strptime`, and different flavors of c accept different directives. In your case (and mine, it seems), the `%z` directive is not accepted.

There's some ambiguity in the doc pages about this. The [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) docs point to the format specification for [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) which doesn't contain a lower-case `%z` directive, and indicates that

> Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms, but only the ones listed here have a meaning standardized by ANSI C.

But then it also points [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) which does contain a lower-case `%z`, but reiterates that

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common.

There's also a [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641) about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

By 'in UTC format' do you actually mean [ISO-8601?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  This is a [pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012592/how-to-convert-this-date-string-to-2011-02-15t12000000-python-datetime-objec) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211362/how-to-parse-xsddatetime-format) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object).